# Time based priority in Active Record Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table which has job listings, which when displayed are normally ordered by the created_at field descending.  I am in the process of adding a "featured" boolean flag which would add the ability for customers to get more visibility to their job listing.  I'd like to have the featured listings pinned to the top of the search results if the job is less than X days old.  How would I modify by existing query to support this?

```
Jobs.where("expiration_date >= ? and published = ?", Date.today, true).order("created_at DESC")
```

Current query pulls back all current, published jobs, ordered by created_at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some other databases (like Oracle) PostgreSQL has a fully functional [**`boolean`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) type. You can use it *directly* in an `ORDER BY` clause without applying a `CASE` statement - those are great for more complex situations.

Sort order for `boolean` values is:

```
FALSE -> TRUE -> NULL
```

If you `ORDER BY bool_expression`**`DESC`**, you invert the order to:

```
NULL -> TRUE -> FALSE
```

If you want `TRUE` first and `NULL` last, use the [**`NULLS LAST`** clause of `ORDER BY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

```
ORDER BY (featured AND created_at > now() - interval '11 days') DESC NULLS LAST  
       , created_at DESC
```

Of course, `NULLS LAST` is only relevant if `featured` or `created_at` *can* be `NULL`. If the columns are defined `NOT NULL`, then don't bother.

Also, `FALSE` would be sorted before `NULL`. If you don't want to distinguish between these two, you are either back to a [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement, or you can throw in [`NULLIF()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) or [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(featured AND created_at > now() - interval '11 days'), FALSE)
                                                                DESC NULLS LAST
       , created_at DESC
```

#### Performance

Note, how I used:

```
created_at > now() - interval '11 days'
```

and *not*:

```
now() - created_at < interval '11 days'
```

In the first example, the expression to the right is a constant that is calculated *once*. Then an index can be utilized to look up matching rows. Very efficient.

The latter cannot usually be used with an index. A value has to be computed for every single row, before it can be checked against the constant expression to the right. Don't do this if you can avoid it. Ever!

Comment: This is a better approach, I can always count on you to correct my (Postgre)?SQL brain damage :) You shouldn't have to worry about NULLs in `created_at` in a Rails app, that should never (ha ha) happen.

Comment: my mind is officially blown - this did it `select id, featured, created_at, title from jobs where published = true and expiration_date >= '10/1/2012' order by (featured and created_at > now() - interval '2 days') desc nulls last, created_at desc;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve here.

I guess you'll be paginating the results. If so, and you want to display featured jobs always on top, regardless of the page, then you should  pull them from the DB separately. If you just want to display them on the first page, order by `published` like this :

```
Jobs.where("expiration_date >= ?", Date.today).order("published DESC, created_at DESC")
```

If you want to pull them separately :

```
@featured_jobs = Jobs.where("expiration_date >= ? and published = ?", Date.today, true).order("created_at DESC")
@regular_jobs = Jobs.where("expiration_date >= ? AND published = ?", Date.today, false).order("created_at DESC") #Paginate them too ... depends on the gem you're using
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  My goal is to have the featured jobs pinned @ the top only if they are less than 7 days old.  After that they fall into the regular created_at ordering.  Was hoping to do this in one query rather than two.  If no one provides a solution in a single query, I'll mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: Can't think of a single SQL request that could handle this ... anyway if you add pagination, you'll need to get the featured jobs separately I think!