# How to order these SQL results in a certain way?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm making a sort of calendar of events app. There are 2 types of events shown on the users home page:

1. nearby event - those with a schedule date within the next 3 days, or within the past 1 hour.
2. normal event - those with either no schedule date, or a schedule date further than 3 days in the future.

This is the **events** table: `id, user_id, content, occurs_at, created_at`

Currently, I'm showing these events ordered by date created to show the newly added stuff first.

What I want is to show all nearby events first and have them ordered by schedule date, then show the normal events and have them ordered by date created. I think it makes for a better user experience, but I don't know how to go about it.

**UPDATE**

Ended up going with this query, which is a combination of a couple of answers.

`ORDER BY COALESCE(occurs_at > :min_time AND occurs_at < :max_time, 0) DESC, occurs_at ASC, created_at DESC`

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: PostgreSQL, through way of SQLAlchemy.

Comment: You can add the *fake* sort column to achieve this (Beth's answer). But as easily you can re-arrange the results of SA query in memory after the events have been retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order by` clauses can contain arbitrary logic, not just field names, so, in pseudo-code, you could have

```
SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY (date_diff(occurs_at, now) <= '3 days'), occurs_at DESC, created_at DESC
```

the first clauses forces all events that occur within the next 3 days to the top of the list. the second clause then orders those in descending order, then everything else gets sorted by the created_at date.

Answer (score 2):

As @MarcB mentions, you can order by an expression, although for PostgreSQL, the expression looks somewhat different;

```
SELECT * FROM Events
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (occurs_at - '3 days'::interval) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
         THEN occurs_at
         ELSE '9999-01-01'::timestamp
         END, created_at;
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f8580/1).

Note, the '9999-01-01' is somewhat kludgily an arbitrarily selected date far into the future, if anyone knows a PostgreSQL constant for "maxdate", I'd be interested :)

Comment: Postgres has something for you. :) [**`'infinity'` and `'-infinity'`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5789). Until v8.3 those were only available for the type `timestamp`. Since v8.4 they work for `date`, too. But I am not convinced we need to go to `infinity` (and beyond!) for this case.

Comment: BTW, +1 for providing a working sqlfiddle. I [built upon it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a45bc/1). I think you missed past events and events with no schedule date. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Verbose format

Easier to explain / understand.

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
        , COALESCE(occurs_at <= (now() + interval '3 days'), FALSE) AS nearby
   FROM   events
   WHERE  occurs_at >= now() - interval '1 hour' -- exclude older events
      OR  occurs_at IS NULL
   )      -- CTE is not strictly necessary, just to make ORDER BY clearer
SELECT *
FROM   x
ORDER  BY
       nearby DESC
     , CASE WHEN nearby THEN occurs_at ELSE created_at END
```

It's not defined explicitly in the question, but the mentioned "no schedule date" makes me assume that `occurs_at` can be `NULL`. So use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL), or `FALSE` and `NULL` will be sorted differently.

- First, order by `nearby` calculated in the CTE `x`.
- Next, order by the respective date (`occurs_at` or `created_at`).

  - `occurs_`at cannot be `NULL` for `nearby` events.
  - And I assume `created_at` is defined `NOT NULL` to begin with. Else you would have to decide where to put `NULL` values.

Other answers here suggest to calculate values based on columns before comparing it to a constant, which can lead to very poor **performance**. Example:

```
date_diff(d,occurs_at, now) <= 3  -- date_diff is also tSQL, not Postgres
```

*Don't* do this if you can avoid it. It forces Postgres to calculate a value for each and every row and makes it impossible to use plain indexes. More infos in this [recent closely related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12681313/939860).

#### Simple version

Shorter, a bit faster.

```
SELECT *
FROM   events
WHERE  occurs_at >= now() - interval '1h'
   OR  occurs_at IS NULL
ORDER  BY
       COALESCE( occurs_at <= (now()::date + 3), FALSE) DESC
     , CASE WHEN occurs_at <= (now()::date + 3)
            THEN occurs_at ELSE created_at END;
```

I took @Joachim's sqlfiddle, simplified the setup, added missing cases (not scheduled, occurred in the past) and ran my queries against it:
**[-> sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a45bc/4)**

Answer (score 1):

I would extend your SELECT clause by a field determining whether or not it's "nearby" (in time, not place)

```
SELECT
id, user_id, content, occurs_at, created_at,
case when date_diff(d,occurs_at, now) <= 3 then 1 else 0 end as isNearby
...
```

but I'm not sure of your syntax, this is for MS SQL Server