# selecting among grouped values in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have created a table

```
create table routes (
   type    character varying
 , quality character varying
 , route   integer
 , fare    integer
);

insert into routes (type, quality, route, fare)
values
  ('X', 'GOOD',    1, 5)
 ,('Y', 'GOOD',    1, 7)
 ,('X', 'AVERAGE', 2, 10)
 ,('Y', 'GOOD',    2, 7)
 ,('X', 'BAD',     3, 8)
 ,('Y', 'BAD',     3, 15);
```

For each route number there are 2 records, I need to select one row(`route,fare`) for each route based on `type` and `quality`.
For example if the `type` is `'X'` and `quality` is '`GOOD'` or `'AVERAGE'`, I will select the `route` and `fare` of that row and move over to next 'route' . Otherwise, I will select the 'route' and 'fare' from row with type  'Y'. That means from the above table, I should get:

```
1,5
2,10
3,15
```

I couldn't figure out to looping through the records of each route and derive the output from the two records of same route.

Comment: Do you use PostgreSQL?

Comment: A clean format helps to comprehend. Also: Do you need the result ordered by `route`? And are there other states than GOOD, BAD and AVERAGE?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (route)
       route, fare
FROM   routes
ORDER  BY route, (type = 'X' AND quality <> 'BAD') DESC, (type = 'X')
```

Fast and produces result ordered by route.
Assuming all columns `NOT NULL`.

#### Explanation

You can order by boolean expressions in Postgres. Details in this related answer:
[Time based priority in Active Record Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679474/time-based-priority-in-active-record-query/12681313#12681313)

We could just use `type DESC` as last `ORDER BY` element, but that would rely on alphabetic sort order while `X` and `Y` look like placeholders for something else.

More explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

[**->SQLfiddle demo.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b405a/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (using JOIN and CASE expresion):

```
SELECT  x.route,
        CASE WHEN x.quality IN ('GOOD', 'AVERAGE' )
             THEN x.fare  ELSE y.fare
        END fare
FROM routes x
JOIN routes y
ON x.type = 'X' AND y.type = 'Y' AND x.route = y.route
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e58441/2

Comment: Looks like a MySQL fiddle accidentally?

Comment: Yes, it's MySql, I'am sorry, it's my mistake. Fortunately it should also work on PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS-SQL - they all support JOINs and case expressions.