# Need to select a JSON array element dynamically from a postgresql table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have data as follows:

```
ID   Name    Data
1    Joe     ["Mary","Joe"]
2    Mary    ["Sarah","Mary","Mary"]
3    Bill    ["Bill","Joe"]
4    James   ["James","James","James"]
```

I want to write a query that selects the LAST element from the array, which does not equal the Name field.  For example, I want the query to return the following results:

```
ID   Name   Last
1    Joe    Mary
2    Mary   Sarah
3    Bill   Joe
4    James  (NULL)
```

I am getting close - I can select the last element with the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Name,
(Data::json->(json_array_length(Data::json)-1))::text AS Last
FROM table;

ID    Name    Last
1     Joe     Joe
2     Mary    Mary
3     Bill    Joe
4     James   James
```

However, I need one more level - to evaluate the last item, and if it is the same as the name field, to try the next to last field, and so on.

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated!

Comment: Crucial: your Postgres version? Data type `json` or `jsonb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `json` in Postgres 9.3

This is hard in pg 9.3, because useful functionality is missing.

#### Method 1

Unnest in a `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` (clean and standard-conforming), trim double-quotes from `json` after casting to `text`. See links below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       t.id, t.name, d.last
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT ('[' || d::text || ']')::json->>0 AS last
  FROM   json_array_elements(t.data) d
  ) d ON d.last <> t.name
ORDER  BY 1, row_number() OVER () DESC;
```

While this works, and I have never seen it fail, the order of unnested elements depends on undocumented behavior.  See links below!
Improved the conversion from `json` to `text` with the expression [provided by @pozs in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956926/need-to-select-a-json-array-element-dynamically-from-a-postgresql-table/27957152?noredirect=1#comment44314918_27957152). Still hackish, but should be safe.

#### Method 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       id, name, NULLIF(last, name) AS last
FROM (
   SELECT t.id, t.name
        ,('[' || json_array_elements(t.data)::text || ']')::json->>0 AS last
        , row_number() OVER () AS rn
   FROM   tbl t
   ) sub
ORDER  BY 1, (last = name), rn DESC;
```

- Unnest in the `SELECT` list (non-standard).
- Attach row number (`rn`) in parallel (more reliable).
- Convert to `text` like above.
- The expression `(last = name)` in the `ORDER BY` clause sorts matching names last (but before NULL). So a matching name is only selected if no other name is available. Last link below.
  In the `SELECT` list, `NULLIF` replaces a matching name with `NULL`, arriving at the same result as above.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d4f13/12)

### `json` or `jsonb` in Postgres 9.4

pg 9.4 ships all the necessary improvements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       t.id, t.name, d.last
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements_text(data) WITH ORDINALITY d(last, rn)
       ON d.last <> t.name
ORDER  BY d.rn DESC;
```

Use `jsonb_array_elements_text()` for `jsonb`. All else the same.

[json / jsonb functions in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

Related answers with more explanation:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [Time based priority in Active Record Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679474/time-based-priority-in-active-record-query/12681313#12681313)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Great answer, but trimming a `json` string can fail, if that string contains some escaping. There is a (hack-ish, i know, but) more reliable way to do the "cast" in 9.3: `('[' || d::text || ']')::json ->> 0` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/99d11/1

Comment: Thanks. That's also what [Marti Raudsepp suggested in the discussion on plpgsql-general](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CABRT9RBTKzSWvuwd7ztXx=b7Sh0Z4gutdXPeE=j30sfV5acCMA@mail.gmail.com). It's better than the alternatives I had before, so I updated with your expression.

Comment: Thanks for this - I will test this afternoon.  Looks promising!